# How can I skip creating tuples with certain values, when using the zip function in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

I am using the zip() function in Python.

I am zipping two lists, however, some lists have the value `0` in them. I would like to avoid any tuples with a zero in them.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [0, 0, 6]
zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(3, 6)]
```

In the process of trying to figure this out, I have also come to realize that any possible solution is probably going to be slow, if it involves zipping then removing.

Is there any way to incorporate a condition on zipping?  Or should I explore a different, faster method?

Any advice is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: you could write your own yield function (can't remember the proper name), to do zip. Then modify it to make the yield conditional. Edit: The list comprehension seems better though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `izip` and only pass through the proper values:

```
from itertools import izip
zipped = [(xx, yy) for xx, yy in izip(x, y) if yy]
```

The reason I choose `izip` over `zip` is because in python2.x, `zip` will generate a new list which really isn't necessary.  `izip` avoids that overhead.

In python3.x, the builtin `zip` doesn't have this list materializing behavior so you should use that instead.  (in fact, `itertools.izip` doesn't even exist in python3.x)

Comment: would be helpful to explain why `izip` instead of `zip`

Answer (score 2):

`zip()` by itself won't cover this particular requirement. Nevertheless you can use it along with list comprehensions to get the desired result:

```
>>>x = [1, 2, 3]
>>>y = [0, 0, 6]
>>>zipped = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(x,y) if a and b]
>>>zipped
[(3,6)]
```

Regarding to the *speed* of this method. It will be a lot faster than any new solution you can create yourself using loops, since the looping in this case is performed natively in C which is faster than Python's loops.

Comment: ...but is it faster than izip?

Comment: @MattO'Brien I probably dare to say yes. `zip()` is implemented in C and `izip()` is implement in `itertools` module (python). Any ways you can use `timeit` to mesure them.

Comment: @PauloBu -- Have you looked at the [`izip` implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1a1a9d6fb278/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l3479) lately?  ;-) -- But you're absolutely correct that the only way to know for sure is to `timeit` (on actual data).

Comment: @mgilson I was so wrong hehe. Thanks for pointing it out! I like itertools now even more! :)